# dynamically insert greater than > | less than < | equals to = operators into a query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app allows filtering via GET.

```
www.mysite.com/rating=5
www.mysite.com/rating>5
www.mysite.com/rating<5
```

I can easily split the `params[:filter]` into:

- `column` (filter)
- `value` (5)
- `operator` (=,>,<)

So after I queried my `Laptop` model and did some basic ordering, I filter the results if set.

```
if params[:filter] != "all"
  .
  .
  case operator
    when "="
      laptops = laptops.where("laptops.rating = ?", value)
    when ">"
      laptops = laptops.where("laptops.rating > ?", value)
    when "<"
      laptops = laptops.where("laptops.rating < ?", value)
  end
end
```

I wondered if there is any way to add the `operator` dynamically similar to the `value`. Especially when I add `>=`, `<=` the code gets repeated **5 times**!

I tried:

```
laptops.where("laptops.rating ? ?", operator, value)
```

but this added the operator as a string, which naturally resulted in an error

`Syntax Error: near "laptops.rating '>' '6'"`

Any ideas how I can make my code more DRY?

Using postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
if params[:filter] != "all"
  .
  .
  # if statement that makes sure operator is one of your valid operators
  if ["<",">",">=","<=","="].include? operator
    laptops = laptops.where("laptops.rating #{operator} ?", value)
  end

end
```

Using ? in a where query tells rails that the parameter should be escaped before inserted into the query which is generally good practice. However - if you first sanitze / validate the operator variable to make sure that it only contains valid characters you should be fine inserting it directly into the query.

That's why rails tells you:

```
Syntax Error: near "laptops.rating '>' '6'"
```

Because the > character where escaped to '>' and no longer a valid SQL-operator.